# How to Bootstrap an VSIX VS2015 Extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, vsix

My extension only gets called if I click on a button. Only than the ctor `CommandHandlerPackage` is called and the `CommandMenu` items are registered.

But I want to `DefaultDisable` the Buttons and only enable them if I open the right Solution. To do that I need to register some Events from `IVsSolutionEvents` but I cant do this from the begining because the extension is initialized only if I interact with it.

So my question is is there something like a bootstrap for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `ProvideAutoLoad` attribute to your Package class like so:

```
[ProvideAutoLoad(UIContextGuids80.SolutionExists)]
public sealed class VSPackage : Package
{
  ...
}
```

This will automatically run the `Initialize` method of your package class when a file or project is open.